# for all file names with .sh

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal

it should display only the file names without the.sh

Example

```
$>./file.sh | cat -e
```

Comment: `find . -type f ! -name "*\.sh"` ? to display all files **not** ending in `'.sh'`, or do you want `find . -type f -name "*\.sh" | sed 's/[.]sh$//'` to output all names `*.sh` stripping the `'.sh'`?

Comment: Multiposted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391872/ .

Answer (score 1):

you can do :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.sh | sed 's|.sh$||'
```

remove the `maxdepth 1` option if you want to find all the files recursively

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `ls | grep -v .sh` to find in the current directory.

> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

If you need system-wide search, you'll need find: 
`find / -type f ! -name "*\.sh"`

- / means root folder
- type f = file
- ! -name  = not sending with .sh